# Grails 3.0 generated ControllerSpec

Tags: grails, controller, specifications

Still a Grails newbie, really enjoying the learning and problem solving but occasionally something that looks really simple just stumps me.

The Grails generated ControllerSpec classes include some sensible tests most of them are straightforward but is there anyone who could give me an explanation of some syntax/logic in this test:

```
    void "Test the index action returns the correct model"() {

    when:"The index action is executed"
        controller.index()

    then:"The model is correct"
        !model.fooBarList
        model.fooBarCount == 0
}
```

In particular the following line:

```
!model.fooBarList
```

The logic seems wrong to me, calling `controller.index()` will populate `model.fooBarList` so why assert that it doesn't exist?

Totally expecting a doh moment here, but I'm going to need help getting there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The logic seems wrong to me, calling controller.index() will populate model.fooBarList so why assert that it doesn't exist?

It isn’t really asserting that `fooBarList` does not exist.  `model.fooBarList` should be an empty list which will also pass that test.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that helps me part of the way and the fact that the List does exist makes sense, but maybe I'm having a slow day, so if `model.fooBarList` is an empty list then why test it with the Not `!` operator?

Comment: @Stryder Take a look at how [Groovy Truth](http://www.groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) works.

Comment: Having just realised it must be the `!` Not operator that is catching me out and then heading to the [Groovy Operators Guide](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_not_operator)  the operator use makes more sense now and since the Grails generated code is meant to be replaced anyway I'll not get hung up on what the author of `!model.modelList` was trying to get at.